# Why does this limit exist $x^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was wondering what is the value of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x^{x}$.

Assuming that the limit exists, I could show using the usual logarithm techniques that the limit is $1$. However, I am not able to show that the limit exists. Could some one help on that?

**EDIT:** It would be so nice if we could do it without l'Hopital...

Comment: Maple helps you with it by the $
Student[Calculus1][LimitTutor]();
 $ command. See the output in the [screen](http://rapidshare.com/files/4063322280/screen22.08.13.docx).

Comment: What for without l'Hopital?

Comment: Are ruler and compass allowed?

Comment: BTW, the l'Hopital rule also bases the existence of the limit $\lim_{x\to a+} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)}$ if the limit $\lim_{x\to a+} \frac {f'(x)} {g('x)}$ exists.

Comment: Considering all the comments together, "ruler and compass" is a way of saying that the restriction to do it without L'Hopital is (in one user's opinion) unnatural, unnecessary, undesirable, or un-somethingelse.  That is one answer to the question about this on the meta site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+} x\cdot\ln x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258273/how-do-i-prove-that-lim-x-to0-x-cdot-ln-x-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Using the change of variable $x=e^{-t}$ show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln x = 0.$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln x = \lim_{t \to +\infty} -\frac{t}{e^t} = 0.$$

To prove the last equality you can use the Taylor expansion for $e^t$, for instance.

Comment: Using Taylor expansion is basically L'Hopital. Which OP wants to avoid if possible.

Comment: He added that condition after my answer. Then he can prove $\frac{t}{e^t} \to 0$ first for natural numbers (e.g., using binomial formula) then extend it to reals.

Comment: This makes perfect sense as for me, $e^{x}$ is defined as the series expansion.

Answer (score 7):

By the l'Hôpital theorem we have

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\log x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log x}{\frac 1 x}=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac 1 x}{\frac{ 1 }{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to0}x=0$$

and conclude with
$$x^x=e^{x\log x}$$

**Edited** To find the limit without the l'Hôpital theorem: for $0<x<1$:
$$  0\leq|x\log x|=x\int_x^1\frac{dt}{t}\leq x\int_x^1\frac{dt}{t^{3/2}}=-2x\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\Big|_x^1\to0$$

Comment: That is a nice answer. But can we do it without recourse to l'Hopital?

Comment: @ Vishal: What for?

Comment: @Vishal I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you know 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$
Proof:

> $$1 \leq \sqrt[n]{n}<\frac{n-2+2\sqrt n}{n}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{GM \leq AM}$$

Now for each $x$ near zero define $n(x)=[\frac{1}{x}]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the integral part function. Let's call $n(x)$
out of simplicity $n$.

Therefore 
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{n} \geq x \geq \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{}{} \Rightarrow\\
\left (\frac{1}{n} \right )^\frac{1}{2n}\geq &\left (\frac{1}{n} \right )^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \geq x ^{x}\geq 
\left (\frac{1}{n+1} \right )^\frac{1}{n} \geq  \left (\frac{1}{2n} \right )^\frac{1}{n}&
\end{align}

And because as $x$ tends to zero $n(x)$ tends to infinity taking limits at both sides you are done.