# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}{x^x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}{x^x}$$

*This question appeared in a calculus exam, and I would like to see different approaches and solutions to the problem.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which approach did you use?

Comment: @yiyi My solution/approach appears below in the answers.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $x \to 0^+$ instead of $x \to 0$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Probably yes, because it is otherwise not defined.

Comment: Right, it's probably obvious.  Maybe it was not worth pointing out :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473535/why-does-this-limit-exist-xx

Comment: @NightRa, didn't see your name on the answer.

Comment: @NightRa You shouldn't have edited your solution in an answer but inside your question, which at the moment is but a PSQ. (=poorly stated question=problem statement question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's define the limit as $L$:
$$\lim_{x\to0}{x^x}=L$$
Then, we can take a logarithm:
$$\ln(L)=\ln(\lim_{x\to0}x^x)=\lim_{x\to0}{x\ln(x)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}{x\ln(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
Now we can apply L'Hopital's rule:
$$\ln(L)=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to0}{-x}=0$$
Then, let's return to $L$:
$$\ln(L)=0\implies L=e^0=1$$