# How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{1/x}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}  x^{1/x}=0$

It looks like on of those situations in which l'hospital will come in handy but that doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this limit exist $x^{x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473535/why-does-this-limit-exist-xx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try to find the limit of logarithm of the function and use $\ln (x^{1/x})=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$. Then you get $\ln L=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ where $L$ is the limit.

Comment: I've tried that. But I don't now how to find this limit. L'hospital doesn't work since it's $\infty /0$. 
I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: You do not really need to use Hopital here, because $-\infty/0^+$ is indeed $-\infty$ and so $\ln L=-\infty$ and $L=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim x^{1/x} = e^{ \lim \log(x)/x}.$

Answer (score 0):

If $x<1$ then $x^{1/x}<x$