# $\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \ln x$ without l'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a midterm coming up and on the past exams the hard question(s) usually involve some form of $\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \ln x$. However, we're not allowed to use l'Hopital's rule, on this year's exam anyways.

So how can I evaluate said limit without l'Hopital's rule? I got somewhere with another approach, don't know if it's useful:

1. $\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \ln x = \lim_{x\to0^{+}} x^2 \ln (x^2) = L$
2. $= (\lim_{x\to0^{+}} 2x)(\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \ln x)$
3. $= 0 * L$

Then I just need to prove that L is finite/exists (which means it must be 0)

Comment: Observing that $x\ln x=\ln(x^x),$ this question is effectively a duplicate of [this other one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473535/why-does-this-limit-exist-xx).

Comment: I do not believe this should be closed, since it describes an interesting **aproach** to the problem that is absent elsewhere.

Comment: Lovely boldfaced typo. Have a sticky p key. Also shift.

Comment: @Raekye : That is a very clever approach.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Couldn't the approach be posted to the other post? I think it would make sense.

Comment: It was the idea of @Raekye. If OP feels like borrowing the little filling in I did, OP is welcome to write it as an answer to the other post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea you described is a **very** nice one. We fill in the details.

We consider, as in the OP,  $x^2\ln(x^2)$, that is, $(2x)(x\ln x)$.  If we can show that $x\ln x$ is **bounded**
near $0$, it will follow by Squeezing that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\ln(x^2)=0$, and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\ln t=0$.

Let $f(x)=x\ln x$. Then $f'(x)=1+\ln x$. It follows that $f(x)$ is decreasing in the interval $(0,e^{-1})$. It reaches a minimum value of $-e^{-1}$ at $x=e^{-1}$.

Since $f(x)$ is negative in our interval, we have $|x\ln x|\le e^{-1}$ in the interval, and we have shown boundedness.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I thought I had to use the derivative to show "which direction the function is going" but couldn't spell it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: A deleted answer gives another way to show that $f(x)$ is bounded:  $$0>x\ln(x)=x\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt\geq x(\frac1x(x-1))=x-1>-1$$ when $0<x<1$, so $|f(x)|\leq 2$ when $0<x<1$.

Comment: (Now that $f(x)=x\ln(x)$ instead of $2x\ln(x)$, the last line of my comment should say "$|f(x)|\leq 1$".)

Comment: Sorry about the little change, in checking for my usual typos I thought there was no point in dragging the $2$ around.

Comment: @Raekye: Please note that in my opinion the approach of user@17762 is "better." My answer was an exercise in pushing through your clever idea.

Answer (score 14):

Let $x=e^{-t}$ and note that as $x \to 0^+$, we have $t \to \infty$. Hence,
$$L = \lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) = \lim_{t \to \infty} -te^{-t} = -\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t}{e^t}$$
Now recall that $e^t \geq \dfrac{t^2}2$, because
$$e^t =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!} \geq \frac{t^2}{2}$$
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t}{e^t} \leq \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac2t = 0$$
This gives us $L=0$.

Comment: Ah this makes sense too. I selected Andre's answer though because he answered earlier. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Can you explain why e^t >= t^2/2 ? I’m not good at math.

Comment: @plhn All of the terms in the series for $e^t$ are positive, so the whole series must be greater than any individual term, in particular, than $\frac{t^2}{2}$.