Another solution
So, I am thinking of ways to solve $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x$. One way is certainly this
$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x = \lim_{x \to 0}e^{\ln(x^x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}e^{x\ln(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \to 0}x\ln(x)}$,
and then the solution boils down to calculating $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x)$. But then the only solution I know of is applying L'Hopital rule, i.e.
$\lim_{x \to 0}x\ln(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x^2}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} -x = 0$,
which means that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^x = e^0=1$.
Now, my question is - is it somehow possible to solve this without L'Hopital rule? I have some foggy remembering that there is in fact a way to solve this by approximating basically $x^x$ with $(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ but I am meddling with inequations and inequalities but to no awail.
All help is appreciated. Thankies!

You can only take right-hand limit. Use the fact that $x \ln (\frac 1 x) =2x \ln \sqrt {\frac 1  x}\le 2x(\frac 1 {\sqrt x}-1)$.

Do you mean this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/769998/42969, or this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935657/42969 ?

In the first link I can't possibly use the first equation. That is in fact my entire question - if someone does not know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} f(n)$, then how can we explain this concrete problem to him?

The second link sounds more reasonable. But the problem here is where I teach they do not get thought theorem of two cops (i.e. if $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ and limits of $a_n$ and $c_n$ are the same then limit of $b_n$ is their common value).
