# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x$ without l'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ without derivatives.

Comment: so... how far have you got?

Comment: How would you apply l'Hôpital here anyway?

Comment: @TMM $x^x = e^{x ln x}$. From there it's obvious with l'Hopital.

Comment: How rigorous do you need to be?  Can you use a table of values or a graph to estimate this?

Comment: The limit does not exist. I assume you meant limit from the right?

Comment: @user7530 noted. I made the same assumption

Comment: @Jan: It's a bit of both. In any case it would be better if the OP added his own thoughts, e.g. how he would solve this with l'Hopital and where he should use something else now.

Comment: @Jan (And some people (like me) were raised without l'Hopital's rule, so using l'Hopital here surely wouldn't be the first thing that comes to my mind.)

Comment: Suggestion: Try writing $x = e^{-y}$ and taking $y \to +\infty$.  Then use the fact that $e^y$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473535/why-does-this-limit-exist-xx/478581#478581

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We wish to find $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^{x}$. Notice

$$x^{x}=e^{x\ln(x)}=e^{(-1)\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{x})}{(\frac{1}{x})}}$$

so it suffices to find $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\ln(y)}{y}$.

$$\frac{\ln(y)}{y}=\frac{1}{y}\int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{t}dt.$$

For $y\ge1$ we have that $\sqrt{y}\le y$ so $\frac{1}{y}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ so:

$$\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\le\frac{1}{y}\int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\frac{1}{y}(2\sqrt{y}-2)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{2}{y}.$$

But also $\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\ge0$ for $y\ge1$. By squeeze theorem the limit is $0$. Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^{x}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what i'm doing is right, please feel free to add comments if i was wrong: $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{x} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[x]{x}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt[x]{x}}=1$

Comment: I don't see how finding $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{x}$ is any different

Comment: Also $x^x$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{x^{1/x}}$.