# What is the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ ($\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x^x$)?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}x^x=$?

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}x^x=$?

**UPDATE:**

According to [this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eubvmnmfikt):

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}x^x=1$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}x^x=1$

Does that make sense?

Comment: Back to you: what is the definition of $x^x$?

Comment: Your update is correct. But 'look at this graph' isn't a proof!

Comment: @Clive Newstead: I know, I added it before you answered, just to improve the question; just reading your answer...

Comment: Your link doesn't lead to any graph. [This one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%5Ex) does but is restricted to $x>0$. So, I (also) wonder what is ***your*** definition of $x^x$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $x^x=e^{x\log x}$ and the exponential function is continuous, so it suffices to know what $x\log x$ does as $x \to 0^{\pm}$.

To work out $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$ you can apply l'Hôpital's rule to the following:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\log x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log x}{1/x} = \underbrace{\cdots \cdots \cdots}_{\text{you do this bit}}$$

As for $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x$, notice that when $x<0$
$$\log(x) = \log |x| + i\arg(x) = \log (-x)+i\pi$$
Now you get something slightly different:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} x\log x = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\log (-x) + i\pi}{1/x} = \underbrace{\cdots \cdots \cdots}_{\text{you do this bit}}$$

*Aside:* for the $x \to 0^-$ case you have to pick a branch of the logarithm. I chose $\pi$, but strictly speaking any $(2k+1)\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ would work (and give you the same answer).

Comment: How about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760451/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-j-to0-lim-k-to-infty-frackjj-ek)?

Answer (score 2):

I would try a logarithmic approach. What is $$L:=\lim_{x \to 0}\ln(x^x)=\lim_{x \to 0} x\ln(x)?$$
Take that value and evaluate $e^L$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}x^x=\exp{\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}x\ln{x}}$$

Write $x\ln{x}$ as $\frac{\ln{x}}{1/x}$ and apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Or [avoid this rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473535).