# Nasty Limit with Logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms

It is maybe a simple question but right now I am not able to see it.

For $r,q,B>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, why is the following limit equal to $1$:
$$\lim_{d\to 0^+}\exp\left[\left(\frac{d}{1-q}\right)\log\left(\log B+\frac1d\log\left(1+\frac{x}{rq}\right)\right)\right]=1$$

I am thinking it has to do with an expansion of $\log\left( \log (x)\right)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,
$$  \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \exp\left[\left({d \over 1-q}\right)\log\left(\log B + {1 \over d}\log \left( 1+{x \over rq} \right) \right) \right]$$
equals
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \exp\left[\log\left(\log B + {1 \over d}\log \left( 1+{x \over rq} \right) \right) \right]^{{d \over 1-q}} $$
equals
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \left(\log B + {1 \over d}\log \left( 1+{x \over rq} \right) \right)^{{d \over 1-q}} $$
and take the limit from there.

More: Since $B$, $x$, $r$, and $q$ are constants, the limit has the form
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \big(a+{b \over d}\big)^{d} $$
which equals
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \big({ad+b \over d}\big)^{d} $$
which equals
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ {(ad+b)^b \over d^b} $$
Now the limit
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} {(ax+b)^n \over x^n}, \qquad n \in \mathbf{R}\backslash\{0\} $$
can be shown to be $a$ by L'Hopital's rule. Choose some $n$, and the limit we are working with becomes
$$ \lim_{d \to 0^+}\ \left({(ad+b)^n \over d^n}\right)^{d \over n} $$
Where the limit of the inside is simply $a$, so overall the limit tends to $1$.

Comment: It is $d \to 0^{+}$.

Comment: Right, fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not actually help. My problem is at the $1/0$ inside the limit and $0$ at the exponent. How to deal with this.

Comment: Does the added material help?

Comment: Thank you yes it did help indeed.

Answer (score 2):

*Advice: you have too many symbols in the expression that serve no purpose in computing the limit, and just make things look unnecessarily complicated. Get "rid" of them.*

Since $r,q,B$ and $x$ are simply nice constants and $d$ is the only parameter that varies, we can rewrite
$$
\exp\left[\left(\frac{d}{1-q}\right)\log\left(\log B+\frac1d\log\left(1+\frac{x}{rq}\right)\right)\right]
$$
as the simpler-looking
$$
\exp\left[\alpha d\log\left(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{d}\right)\right]
$$
for some (related) constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. To prove this converges to $1$ when $d\to 0^+$ is equivalent, by continuity of the exponential, to proving the exponent converges to $0$. From there, observe that
$$
 d\log\left(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{d}\right)
=
 d\log\left(\frac{1}{d}\left(\gamma+d\beta\right)\right)
=
 d\log\frac{1}{d} +  d\log\left(1+d\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\right)
$$
and both terms converge to $0$ when $d\to 0^+$ (the first as $\lim_{u\to 0^+} u\log u = 0$, the second as the product of $d\to 0$ and $\log\left(1+d\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\right) \to \log(1+0)=0$). Multiplying by the constant $\alpha$ does not change anything, so the exponent does converge to $0$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you, it is the correct answer but @ate provided it a bit earlier, therefore I think I should take his answer as the correct one, right?

Comment: Maybe you could explain why $x \log x$ tends to 0 as $x$ does, or provide a reference. I think Mitscaype is looking for highly explicit proofs.

Comment: @Mitscaype That is literally up to you -- I won't get sad or grumpy if you do.

Comment: @Mitscaype I would have thought it standard, but [this, for instance](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258273/how-do-i-prove-that-lim-x%E2%86%920-x%E2%8B%85-ln-x-0).

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: This is the same as saying the expression inside the brackets $\to 0.$ Inside the brackets you have, essentially, $d\log (C_1 +C_2/d).$ That indeed goes to $0.$

Comment: But why does it go to $0$. I just would like to see the proof, that's all. Mathematica also says it goes to zero etc, but I am not able to prove it on my own.

Comment: You could write it as $\log(C_1+ C_2/d)/(1/d).$ That is an $\infty/\infty$ form, so we can apply L'Hopital. The quotient of derivatives is $1/(C_1 + C_2/d).$ The denominator $\to \infty$ so this expression $\to 0.$