# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{(1+x)^2}-\ln\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried :$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{(1+x)^2}-\ln\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{(1+x)^2}-\ln x+\ln (x+1)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-x^2\ln x}{(1+x)^2}+\ln(x+1)$$

Here I can use $\ln(x+1)\sim x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}$. but it seems It doesn't work because I don't know how to simplify $\cfrac{-x^2\ln x}{(1+x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $(1+x)^2-1$ isn't $x^2$. I should be$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{-x(x+2)\ln x}{(1+x)^2}+\ln(x+1)\right)=-2\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0.$$(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258273/how-do-i-prove-that-lim-x-to0-x-cdot-ln-x-0) for proofs that $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0$.)

Comment: I don't understand how you get $-2\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x$. Did you express that as$\cfrac{-x(x+2)\ln x}{(1+x)^2}=\cfrac{-\ln x\times x^2-2\ln x\times x}{x^2+2x+1}$?

Comment: @soheil I used $\lim_{x\to0^+}\tfrac{x+2}{(1+x)^2}=2$.

Comment: I got it, Can we always say limit of product of two functions is equal to product of their limit?

Comment: @soheil You can say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ provided $F:=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $G:=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist and their product isn't the [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) $0\times\pm\infty$. In this case $F=2,\,G=0$. For the case where $F,\,G$ are finite, see the product rule of limits [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules).

Comment: Very good explanation, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is $0$

And the last step should give you

$\ln(x)-\ln(\frac{x}{1+x})(1+x^2)$ and as $x=0$ it gives you $0$!